# Datatable jquery to limit number of selectable rows to maximum of 5 on checkbox select

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am using datatables example: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html to select multiple rows using checkboxes. This is working fine. I can select multiple rows holding the Ctrl key. The bottom of the table displays the number of rows selected. The issue I am having is I want to stop the user from selecting more than 5 rows. How can I tweak the JQUERY to limit to maximum 5 rows selected and then it prevents the user from selecting anymore unless they de-select a row?

```
var table = $('#tabledt').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
        
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, ix) {
    var selected = dt.rows({ selected: true });
    if (selected.count() > 5) {
        dt.rows(ix).deselect();
    }
});
```